# Push notification Android GCM - how to clear a Message?

Tags: android, delphi, google-cloud-messaging

Delphi XE8, I send a Message by json to the GCM. After click the Message I read it by...:

```
var
  LNotification: TPushServiceNotification;
begin
  for LNotification in AServiceConnection.Service.StartupNotifications do
  begin
    if Assigned(LNotification) and (LNotification.Json.ToString<>'') then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Enter by Notification Click: ' +     LNotification.Json.ToString);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Could you help me to clear the Message from Push panel?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot remove one specific push notification, but to remove all, add `TNotificationCenter` component and use `CancelAll` method.

P.S: if application is running when push is received, clicking it will remove.